# Whenever I open terminal in visual studio code the terminal is blank and cant type a single word in it

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to open terminal of visual studio code my terminal remains blank and I am not able to type anything in the terminal I have switched power shell to command prompt but the same issue persist [I have included the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RbW3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening VSC as an administrator